# Performance Tuning an AWK?

Tags: bash, performance, awk

I've written a simple parser in BASH to take apart csv files and dump to a (temp) SQL-input file.  The performance on this is pretty terrible; when running on a modern system I'm barely cracking 100 lines per second.  I realize the ultimate answer is to rewrite this in a more performance oriented language, but as a learning opportunity, I'm curious where I can improve my BASH skills.
I suspect there are gains to be made by writing to an ram instead of to a file, then flushing all the text at once to the file, but I'm not clear on where/when BASH gets upset about memory usage (largest files I've parsed have been under 500MB).

The following code-block seems to eat most of the cycles, and as I understand, needs to be processed linearly due to checking timestamps (the data has a timestamp, but no timedate stamp, so I was forced ask the user for the start-day and check if the timestamp has cycled 24:00 -> 0:00), so parallel processing didn't seem like an option.

```
        while read p; do
          linetime=`printf "${p}" | awk '{printf $1}'`
          # THE DATA LACKS FULL DATESTAMPS, SO FORCED TO ASK USER FOR START-DAY & CHECK IF THE DATE HAS CYCLED
          if [[ "$lastline" > "$linetime" ]]
              then
            experimentdate=$(eval $datecmd)
          fi
          lastline=$linetime
          printf "$p" | awk -v varout="$projname" -v experiment_day="$experimentdate " -v singlequote="$cleanquote" '{printf "insert into tool (project,project_datetime,reported_time,seconds,intensity) values ("singlequote""varout""singlequote","singlequote""experiment_day $1""singlequote","singlequote""$1""singlequote","$2","$3");\n"}' >> $sql_input_file
```

Ignore the singlequote nonsense, I needed this to run on both OSX & 'nix, so I had to workaround some issues with OSX's awk and singlequotes.

Any suggestions for how I can improve performance?

Comment: To improve performance, either: 1) rewrite everything in `awk` or in another language OR 2) don't use so many useless subshells and pipes! your line `printf "${p}" | awk '{printf $1}'` is ridiculous and the last `awk` is ridiculous too. You should use `read` as: `while read -r linetime secondfield thirdfield; do ...; done`. The second and third fields of the line are in the corresponding variables. Also, the line `experimentdate=$(eval $datecmd)` looks ridiculous and it's very slow: it spawns a subshell for nothing (and is very likely broken). What is `datecmd`?

Comment: `datecmd` is variable that sets based on the OS type.  Codeblock for it is:
   
`if [[ $OSTYPE == *"linux"* ]]
   # LINUX AND OSX/BSD HAVE DIFFERENT DATE COMMANDS. CHECKING WHICH OS THE HOST RUNS AND CHOOSING ACCORDINGLY.
              then
                date -d "$experimentdate" +%Y-%m-%d > /dev/null  2>&1
              else
                date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" "$experimentdate" +%Y-%m-%d > /dev/null  2>&1
          fi
          is_valid="$?"
`
This is due to OSX & 'nix packaging different versions of the date command by default. :(

Comment: Don't put this in a variable! create a _function_ instead!

Comment: This is probably more suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Every time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice and rewrite your script after reading the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. Oh, and the singlequote nonsense has nothing to do with awk, no shell will allow you to use single quotes inside a a single quote delimited script and the common workaround is to use `\047` in its place.

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you.  That link was **exactly** what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to start awk for every line you process in a loop. Replace your loop with awk or replace awk with builtin commands.
Both awk's are only used for printing. Replace these lines with additional parameters to the `printf` command.
I did not understand the codeblock for `datecmd` (not using `$linetime` but using the output variable `experimentdate`), but this one should be optimised: Can you use regular expressions or some other trick?
So you do not have the tune `awk`, but decide to use awk completely or get it out of your while-loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your performance would improve if you did all the processing with awk.  Awk can read your input file directly, express conditionals, and run external commands.

Awk is not the only one either.  Perl and Python would be well suited to this task.